# NSUserDefault takes a few seconds to store the value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

As the title says, I am trying to store coins in `NSUserDefault`.

This is how I register it in the `AppDelegate -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let defaults:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.register(defaults: ["firstLaunch":true,
                             "name":"",
                             "mycoins":0,
                             "didRate":false,])
```

That works just fine.

This is currently how I store it:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func incrementIntegerForKey(key:String, by: Int) {
        let int = integer(forKey: key)
        set(int + by, forKey:key)
    }
}

UserDefaults.standard.incrementIntegerForKey(key: "mycoins", by: +1)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

I am using this to check for the amount:

```
print("Coins: \(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "mycoins"))")
```

So let's say I increment the score a few times, and fully closes the app 2 seconds after running the increment and sync function, the new score doesn't fully store. Maybe one or two coins get's stored, but not all five. Now - if I wait 7-10 seconds after running that same function, it get's stored perfectly.

What am I doing wrong here? I am using `synchronize()` so it doesn't wait for the sync. How can I make it store at the exact time?

Comment: From the docs **"Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."** Note also that this method returns true if the data was saved successfully to disk, otherwise false.

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok, but that still doesn't answer why the data takes up to ten seconds to store.

Comment: It does it says "Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database"

Comment: Note that UserDefaults it is meant to persist the UI state. You can simply structure your data and persist it writing it to disk synchronously

Comment: @LeoDabus I just removed the `synchronize()` code, and I still have to wait up to ten seconds before the data get's stored. Tried to close the app after three seconds - the coins was not stored.

Comment: Well I never said removing the call to the method would solve your issue. Again you should structure your data (create a codable model) and write it synchronously to disk. This way it will be written immediately on the main thread.

Comment: @LeoDabus Would Core Data be a good option here? Even though I only need to store an Integer value?

Comment: I don't think you need Core Data for this. Just write the codable data as a json file inside a directory named with your app bundle identifier at your application support directory.